# Query to detect changes in item location from one day before (RFID tracking)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some RFID tags on itens, which generate some data on a table.
Unfortunately, the reports on this system are poorly to non existant, and I want to make one.
Consider my data somethings as this. Everytime we "query" the system, it scans and inserts all item data on the same table:

[image]

My desired output, when using 02/03/2020 day as base, is this (based on the location):

[image]

I've done some color (based on the address column) on the first picture to better ilustrate.
In this example, you can see all possible status:

- No change (ITEM_ID stood on the same place as the day before)
- Item left forever (was sold, so it is not on any other place - example as ITEM_ID 00006)
- Item was moved from address A to B (example ITEM_ID 0005: was on A104 and now is in A110)
- New item added on a unused address (example ITEM_ID 0008, another bag)
- New item on a address used yesterday (example ITEM_ID 0009 which was put on A104, used the day before by ITEM_ID 0005)

Someone told me that this can be accomplished by using ROLLUP or CUBE, but I'm not sure if it is the best approach, or how to use it.

The totals are a plus. I can export data do Excel and do a count based on the STATUS column (or even another select)

In summary, it is a tracking report.

ANY tips will be kindly appreciated.

SQL SERVER is Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Standard

Comment: Do not use images for adding tables to a post. No one can consume that easily for any test without a lot typing everything. In fact an image of a table is more or less like no table at all. Use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements as **text**. Or at least tabular text.

Comment: 1. I agree with @stickybit -- it's much easier for us to help if you give us code (rather than images) to work with; 2. You should ask your question as simple as possible. The `qty` field is not necessary for your query. 3. You should not have a column called `date` since it is a reserved word in SQL.

Comment: Thank you both stickybit and mankowitz. I'll do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to join the table with itself to track where things are going. I don't think I've addressed all of your concerns, but this should be a good place to start.

```
CREATE TABLE rfid 
  ( 
     item_id     INT, 
     address     VARCHAR(50), 
     description VARCHAR(50), 
     qty         INT, 
     [date]      DATE 
  ) 

INSERT INTO rfid 
            (item_id, 
             address, 
             description, 
             qty, 
             [date]) 
VALUES      (1, 
             'a100', 
             'cable', 
             100, 
             '2020-01-03'), 
            (2, 
             'a101', 
             'charger', 
             100, 
             '2020-01-03'), 
            (3, 
             'a102', 
             'laptop', 
             100, 
             '2020-01-03'), 
            (4, 
             'a103', 
             'chair', 
             100, 
             '2020-01-03'), 
            (5, 
             'a104', 
             'basket', 
             100, 
             '2020-01-03'), 
            (6, 
             'a105', 
             'bag', 
             100, 
             '2020-01-03'), 
            (1, 
             'a100', 
             'cable', 
             100, 
             '2020-02-03'), 
            (2, 
             'a101', 
             'charger', 
             100, 
             '2020-02-03'), 
            (3, 
             'a102', 
             'laptop', 
             100, 
             '2020-02-03'), 
            (4, 
             'a103', 
             'chair', 
             100, 
             '2020-02-03'), 
            (5, 
             'a110', 
             'basket', 
             100, 
             '2020-02-03'), 
            (8, 
             'a200', 
             'bag', 
             100, 
             '2020-02-03'), 
            (9, 
             'a104', 
             'keyboard', 
             100, 
             '2020-02-03'); 

WITH inventory_new (item_id, address, description) 
     AS (SELECT item_id, 
                address, 
                description 
         FROM   rfid 
         WHERE  [date] = '2020-02-03'), 
     inventory_old (item_id, address, description) 
     AS (SELECT item_id, 
                address, 
                description 
         FROM   rfid 
         WHERE  [date] = '2020-01-03') 
SELECT COALESCE(o.item_id, n.item_id)         item_id, 
       COALESCE(o.description, n.description) description, 
       CASE 
         WHEN o.address = n.address THEN 'no change' 
         WHEN o.address IS NULL THEN 'in' 
         WHEN n.address IS NULL THEN 'out' 
       END                                    outcome 
FROM   inventory_old o 
       FULL OUTER JOIN inventory_new n 
                    ON ( n.item_id = o.item_id )
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it looks promissing so far.

I added some columns to the query (qty and address), but i can not understand why item 0005 status on address A104 is null. The correct should be OUT, since it left the address that day. And this condition is already on the CASE, even it would mark as "in" - (WHEN o.address IS NULL THEN 'in' )

Comment: Oh I think I found the problem: ITEM 0005 switched address, and new address A110 does not show on the result, because COALESCE is returning first the old address, and it has both results... Any tips to fix it?

Comment: Add another line for the case statement, e.g. `WHEN o.address <> n.address THEN 'Item has moved' `

Comment: Also... So others can help: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/233d10/2

Comment: hi @mankowitz, thanks for the help. I've put my last version on sqlfiddle. For the case statement, I done it exactly as yours (hey, i'm on the right track :-) ). But the only problem I got so far is for the item which has moved  (ID 5). It should appear a row with address A110, and there is none.

Comment: oh, I think I got it, just changed coalesce order for address. Do you mind take a look and see if my thinking is right?

Comment: Try this:  `FROM   inventory_old o 
       FULL OUTER JOIN inventory_new n 
                    ON ( n.item_id = o.item_id and n.address=o.address)` on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/233d10/10

Comment: thank you so much ! I think this solves the problem! as a extra, there is a way to add the 'totals' at the botom?